# How is disk utilization measured?

Tags: filesystems, performance

For context, I am a self-taught developer, and I picked up Cloud operations along the way. I gained the interest on Performance, so I picked up the book "Systems Performance" by Brendan Gregg.

In the book, there is a case study about slow disks. It appears that the "disk utilization" is at 80%.

I'm trying to figure out how "disk utilization" is measured. I am aware of `iostat` as described in this doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7229/6j6q8svh7/index.html

It is still not clear to me what specific metrics should I extract to come up with disk utilization by %.